# Python launching problems OS X

Tags: macos, bash, python

I'm trying to install python on mac OS X 10.7.5. I installed it from MacPort and I think before I did, I screwed up `$PATH` somehow. It seems to install fine but then when I try to run `ipython` I get

```
-bash: ipython: command not found.
```

I thought it had something to do with the path and when I do `/bin/echo $PATH` I get something that seems really weird to me:

```
opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider wierd in PATH?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install ipython in addition to python:

```
$ port search ipython

py-ipython @0.13.2 (python)
An enhanced Interactive Python shell
```

With

```
$ sudo port select --set ipython ipython24
```

you can then select the version you want.

It ill be installed in

```
$ type ipython
ipython is /opt/local/bin/ipython
```

Check that your `PATH` begins with `/opt/local/bin` and not with `opt/local/bin/` (notice the beginning `/`)